# I am trying to setup an Excel sheet to help keep track of our firewall Information

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I am looking for is a formula that when cell "M4" has a value, cell "A16" gets populated with something along the lines of 192.168."Contents of M4".0 I am sure this can be done and I am just overlooking something.

Thanks

Comment: The title of this question needs work. Consider changing it to something similar to, 'How to concatenate strings in Excel'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value in `M4` is 1 the following formula would place the value `192.168.1.0` in the cell it is entered into:

`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($M$4)),CONCATENATE("192.168.",$M$4,".",0),"")`

The logic in this formula is

If `M4` is not blank then the value of this cell is:

`192.168` + `M4` + `.0`

Note that `M4` is refered to as a constant (e.g. `$M$4`) so the value in `M4` will always be used no matter where in the sheet the formula is placed, if this is undesirable, remove the dollar signs